# Is it ok to use a reference return of the converted pointer's value in C#?

Tags: c#, reference, return, fixed, ref

Is it ok to use a reference return of the converted pointer's value?

I have read this question.
[How is return by reference implemented in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57183273/how-is-return-by-reference-implemented-in-c/57187058)

Is it ok to use the code below about garbage collector's memory move problem.
(Helper.GetReference() & Helper.GetPointer())

```
class Program
{
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        ref SomeStruct reference = ref Helper.GetReference<SomeStruct>(bytes);
        reference.field1 = 1;
        reference.field2 = 2;

        SomeStruct* pointer = Helper.GetPointer<SomeStruct>(bytes);
        pointer->field1 = 3;
        pointer->field2 = 4;
    }
}

public static class Helper
{
    // Can I use this?
    public static unsafe ref T GetReference<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : unmanaged
    {
        fixed (byte* p1 = bytes)
        {
            T* p2 = (T*)p1;
            return ref *p2;
        }
    }

    // Shouldn't I use it?
    public static unsafe T* GetPointer<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : unmanaged
    {
        fixed (byte* p1 = bytes)
        {
            return (T*)p1;
        }
    }
}

public struct SomeStruct
{
    public int field1;
    public int field2;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to ask with a good behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Comment: @Sherly Febrianti: Thank you for your edit proposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far i know, both of these methods are **unsafe**... Yes it does compile, however, because you have used `unsafe` in your `Helper` methods and referenced the same memory, your *safety-net* has been blown.

You are *pointing* to a portion of memory (a managed object) that can be moved by the *Garbage Collector* (aka your array), potentially leaving you with a *dangling-pointer*

You would need to *fix* (`fixed`) the array in your `Main` method to ensure safety (they way i see it), or your struct

Eg

```
fixed (byte* p = bytes) // even though p isn't being used
{
   SomeStruct* pointer = Helper.GetPointer<SomeStruct>(bytes);
   pointer->field1 = 3;
   pointer->field2 = 4;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? Is it ok to fix(fixed) SomeStruct like below?.

            fixed (SomeStruct* fixedPointer = &Helper.GetReference<SomeStruct>(bytes))
            {
                s->field1 = 5;
                s->field2 = 6;
            }